# "active" class in AJAX pagination not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm quite new in ajax and javascript, and how can I give a class='active' when the button is clicked.

here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_data();
        function load_data(pages)
        {
            var id=<?php echo $id; ?>;
            $.ajax({
                url:"includes/komentar-ajax.php?id="+id,
                method:"POST",
                data:{page:pages},
                success:function(data){
                    $('#pagination_data').html(data);
                }
            })
        }

        $(document).on('click','.page-link', function(){
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
            var pages = $(this).attr("id");
            load_data(pages);
        });
});
```

Comment: Seems weird that you remove it when it is clicked again, but still load the data. Code looks like it should work. What happens? What is the HTML?

Comment: here
<li class="page-item"><span class="page-link"  id="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></span></li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ajax success function, after setting the $('#pagination_data') html you can then set your active state.

First remove the active class from all .page-link buttons and then set the class active to the one you want.

Your code would look like this:

```
   $.ajax({
            url:"includes/komentar-ajax.php?id="+id,
            method:"POST",
            data:{page:pages},
            success:function(data){
                $('#pagination_data').html(data);
                // remove active class from other buttons
                $('.page-link').removeClass("active");
                // add active class to your button 
                $("#"+id).closest(".page-item").addClass('active');
            }
        })
```

Keep in mind that passing the page as the id of your .page-link buttons may result to duplicate ids and things will stop working. I suggest you use data attributes to store this kind of information in your html elements.

Comment: still don't work, here is my pagination html item
<li class="page-item "><span class="page-link"  id="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></span></li>

Comment: Yes it's clear why, you want to add the active class to the parent element and I was selecting the child. Replace $("#"+id).addClass('active'); with $("#"+id).closest(".page-item").addClass('active'); I'll also update my answer.

Comment: @hiragitukasa, if this solves the problem please mark this answer as solution.